# Programmatically importing local json file react-native

Tags: json, react-native

I have a hand full of json objects I need to load into a react native app. I couldn't find much documentation on how `import sample from '../data/Sample.json';` imports. I will only need to load 1 file depending on what the user selects and I am not sure if I just import all 12 files (1mb total) if that will be more impactful on performance than I need. Is there a way I can selectively load a json file depending on state or user input?

Comment: Have you tried `require()` for importing it? You could set a variable string to the file you need programmatically and call `require(pathToRequiredFile)` to load it. However, `require` caches your files for future use, so keep that in mind of you use it.

Comment: Im not sure how that would work, could you show me an example or point me in the direction of the documentation on require?

Comment: How will you decide which of the 12 files needs to be imported? Based on some variable, etc?

Comment: Yes, a known variable. 1 of 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the links to the JSON files in an array and use `require()` as needed:

```
links = [
  'link_to_file_1.json',
  'link_to_file_2.json',
  // and so on...
];

loadMyFile = (index) => {  // Call this function with required index of list

    if (index)
    {
      let fileUrl = require(links[index]);

      // parse file, perform required actions ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, ill try this out. Looks promising.

Comment: Pops an error: "calls to 'require' expect exactly 1 string literal argument, but this was found 'require(links[index])'

Comment: How are you calling the method?